# Caching data: numpy vs pandas vs MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, numpy, caching

I am currently processing time series data stored into h5 files, each file containing one hour of data.

In order to move towards real time processing, I would like to process time series data, *one second at a time*. The plan is to **aggregate** one second of data, **process** the data, **clear** the cache and **repeat**.

My first idea was to do this using numpy arrays or pandas dataframe, but a colleague suggested caching the data to a MySQL database instead.

In order to benchmark the performance of each approach, I ran a simple timing exercise, trying to access 1,000 samples:

| Method | Execution time |
| --- | --- |
| Pandas | 1.36 µs |
| Numpy | 790 ns |
| MySQL | 552 ns |

The code used to obtain these results is detailed below.

From this limited exercise, it looks like the MySQL approach is the winner, but since most of the processing relies on numpy and pandas functions anyways, I am not sure whether it would make much sense to cache the data into a database prior to writing them to a numpy array or a pandas dataframe.

So here's my question: apart from improved performance, **what are the benefits of using a MySQL database to cache data?**

---

## Benchmark

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import mysql.connector
from timeit import timeit
```

### Pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['test'] = np.arange(1,1000)
%timeit df['test']
```

This returns `1.36 µs ± 26.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`

### Numpy array:

```
%timeit np.arange(1,1000)
```

This returns `790 ns ± 21.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`

### MySQL database:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='mydb')

try:
   cursor = cnx.cursor()
   cursor.execute("""
      select * from dummy_data
   """)
   %timeit result_mysql = [item[0] for item in cursor.fetchall()]
finally:
    cnx.close()
```

This yields `552 ns ± 26.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`

Comment: These timings don't look right to me. I find it hard to believe that you can query a full table across the MySQL server in less time than it takes numpy to initialise an array of 1000 values. Equally, `%timeit df['test']`  isn't doing any assignment, it's just referencing a column

Comment: Also, the premise doesn't seem right to me. Why aren't you doing the aggregation by second inside a single `pandas` dataframe or a MySQL query?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @roganjosh: indeed, the times that I tried comparing are the times needed to "query" the data, not those needed to populate a table (*e.g.* write data into a MySQL table).

Comment: Please re-read my comment; you appear to have the opposite understanding to what I was saying. "I find it hard to believe that you can query a full table across the MySQL server in less time than it takes numpy to initialise an array of 1000 values"

Comment: If I understand your comment properly, it means that I cannot compare `%timeit result_mysql = [item[0] for item in cursor.fetchall()]` with `%timeit df['test']`, because the latter is just referencing a column. How do you suggest to assess the performance of pandas then?

Comment: Well you can - I'm saying the timings are surely wrong. Here's a stupidly simple example https://dpaste.org/nD0Nk . So, even if we're not talking about it having to deal with MySQL result objects and, instead, just the most _basic_ tuple, python takes ~60us, not the order of ns. Removing he assignment to `a` makes no difference

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this snippet. When running your examples into a Jupyter notebook, I end up with `857 ns` for the first and `32.7 µs` for the second.

Comment: I will double check the way I query data from my local MySQL database to understand why I am getting a faster response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two parts of this answer.

---

### Timings

The first thing that should stand out here is that there is no way that a list comprehension should beat the initialisation of a `numpy` array. This is immediately suspicious:

```
%timeit np.arange(1,1000)
790 ns ± 21.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit result_mysql = [item[0] for item in cursor.fetchall()]
552 ns ± 26.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

It's not *impossible* that Python might beat `numpy` on something like this but the probability is vanishingly small (some regression in a new `numpy` release?).

The issue here is that `cursor.fetchall()` returns a generator of results, which can only yield records; the *first* iteration of 1000000 loops goes slow, consumes the iterator, and the remaining 999999 iterations become `[item[0] for item in ()]`.

This becomes more obvious when you run something like this:

```
import numpy as np

def create_array():
    a = np.arange(1, 1000)
​
​
def list_comp(tups):
    a = [item[0] for item in tups]
         
         
test = [(x,) for x in range(999)]
​
# Results
​
%timeit create_array()
2.12 µs ± 230 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
​
%timeit list_comp(test)
61.7 µs ± 4.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

### Actual Approach

I don't really understand your use of `cache` here. There's a couple of things that don't add up for me:

1. You throw the intermediate data away - that's not a cache
2. You don't re-use any pre-allocated memory (less important in python vs. compiled languages, but still can make a difference) - that's not a cache.

Unless you'll explode RAM by pulling all the data, then aggregating on a per-second basis, then I don't see why you're processing it like this. Both `pandas` and `MySQL` will benefit from bulk analysis and then reducing it down to results on a per-second basis. Even with the poor timings from your own investigation, MySQL might actually beat `pandas` in speed, especially if the data is too large to hold in memory.

Bottom line - these speed tests are not suitable on their own to determine anything about what's most appropriate for your actual application. Just don't use MySQL as an interim storage on a per-second basis

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer @roganjosh. The **Timings** sanity check was really insightful. Now, I might not have been clear enough about my **Actual Approach**: I know that I can use pandas to "bulk process" my dataset; in fact, this is what I am currently doing. The reason why I want to analyze one second of data at a time is to have the ability to deliver processed results in quasi real time. I was simply wondering about the best way to stream, aggregate and process these data over short intervals: based on your answer, I will stay away from using a MySQL database for the time being.

Comment: Just to elaborate on my second point of "not a chache" in that case - every time you make a new array, numpy needs to make an allocation I memory, which takes time. If you're always going to have 1000 elements, it would be better just to overwrite the data in the existing array each time to speed things up. I suspect, though, that the number of signals will be highly variable